# Uncaught error in rust

Tags: rust

I have the following code to open a file and handle errors:

```rust
match File::open(&Path::new(file_name_abs.clone())) {
   Some(html_file) => {
       let mut html_file_mut = html_file;
       let msg_bytes: ~[u8] = html_file_mut.read_to_end();
       response.push_str(str::from_utf8(msg_bytes));
   },
   None => {
       println("not found!");
       valid = false;
   }   
}
```

Still when I pass in an invalid file, I have the following error message:

```
task '<unnamed>' failed at 'Unhandled condition: io_error: io::IoError{kind: FileNotFound, desc: "no such file or directory", detail: None}', /private/tmp/rust-R5p2/rust-0.9/src/libstd/condition.rs:139
```

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the file described by `file_name_abs` is not found at the location you specified.  Check the path of the file.

I ran this code (slightly modified) on my system.  It works if the file is found and gives the "file not found" error if it is not, like so:

```
task '<main>' failed at 'Unhandled condition: io_error: io::IoError{kind: FileNotFound, desc: "no such file or directory", detail: None}', /home/midpeter444/tmp/rust-0.9/src/libstd/condition.rs:139
```

Also, you probably don't need to be calling `clone` on `file_name_abs`, but that is a secondary concern and not the cause of the runtime error you are seeing.

**[Update]**: to handle the error at runtime you have a couple of options that I know of:

*Option 1:* Check that the file exists before trying to open it:

```rust
let fopt: Option<File>;
if path.exists() && path.is_file() {
    fopt = File::open(&path);
} else {
    fopt = None;
}
// then do the match here
```

*Option 2*: Use the `io::result` function: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/io/fn.result.html.  This function will trap any IO error and allow you check the `Result<T,Error>` it returns to see if it succeeded or threw an error. Here's an example:

```rust
let path = Path::new(fname);

let result = io::result(|| -> Option<File> {
    return File::open(&path);
});

match result {
    Ok(fopt)      => println!("a: {:?}", fopt.unwrap()),
    Err(ioerror)  => println!("b: {:?}", ioerror)
}
```

or, more idiomatically, (as pointed out by @dbaupp):

```rust
let path = Path::new(fname);

let result = io::result(|| File::open(&path));

match result {
    Ok(fopt)      => println!("a: {:?}", fopt.unwrap()),
    Err(ioerror)  => println!("b: {:?}", ioerror)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How shall I take care of the file not found case? I checked some doc and they suggest something like the `match` I had above. I am wondering what I did wrong here with `match`. Will `None` handle the file not found error?

Comment: No `None` will not handle the error that is thrown. I've suggested two ways two do it above.  There are probably others (I'm still new to Rust).

Comment: Note you can write `io::result(|| File::open(&path))`, the type annotation and `return` are optional.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know you could do it that way!  Nice idiom. I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: Please realise that option 1 does *not* guarantee it will work; there is a race condition there where the file may be removed between your check and the opening of the file. (These are the sorts of things you need to be careful about with security.)